# Fuzzy text in console on external monitor

Tags: display, virtual-console

I have my laptop connected to external monitor as primary display. When I drop to virtual console/terminal, the console text on the monitor looks very fuzzy. Is there way to fix this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: We need your video chipset added to your question, thanks!

Comment: i have the same problem . Have you solved it yet ? 

`lspci -nn |grep -E 'VGA|Display'` 

Output : 

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 [8086:5916] (rev 02)

I have a internal 1366x768 60hz and external 1920x1080 monitor which is connected through hdmi.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, but was able to adjust the Sharpness on my external monitor (Dell 27") using the physical buttons and built-in menu on the actual monitor.

Comment: My Philips monitor has an `AUTO` button that fixed screen sharpness for me.